# how to test the type of an object?

Tags: python

I am confuse about the type test in "if" statement in python. For example, in the following code:

```
x=10
if [isinstance(x, str)]:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

The output is "yes". x=10 is an integer, not a string, but why the code gives 'yes'?

With many thanks

Comment: `if isinstance(x, str)` instead of `if [isinstance(x, str)]`

Answer (score 3):

Use just `isinstance(x, str)` It will execute your expected answer. When you set your condition in `if [isinstance(x, str)]` Then it prints `YES` because `[isinstance(x, str)]` returns a TRUE that's a boolean list. Since the list isn't empty so it prints `YES`.

```
print([isinstance(x, str)])

# Output
# [False]
```

Here `[False]` is a boolean list.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine, [isinstance(x, str)] returns True Because list isn't empty.

```
x=10
if isinstance(x, str):
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've put this boolean value, which is False, inside a list, now python will check if `len([isinstance(x, str)]) > 0` and since that's true, it prints "yes"